# Solve $x^2(x^2+1)y''-2x^3y'+2(x^2-1)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

> Find both solutions to $x^2(x^2+1)y''-2x^3y'+2(x^2-1)y=0$, given that
>   one of the solutions is of the form $y_1 = x^n$ or $e^{ax}$.

I can solve $x^2y''+Cxy'+Dy=0$ equations, but dividing by $x^2$ in this case results in an equation which I'm not sure how to solve either.

Basically how to solve equations of the form $Ax^2y''+Bxy'+Cy=0$ where $A, B, C$ are functions of $x$.

Comment: the solution contains the hypergeometric series

Comment: you can use laplace transform or suppose that y=sigma(aix^n) and obtain ai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation has no solutions of the given forms.  I suspect you meant
$$ x^2 (x^2 + 1) y'' - 2 x^3 y' + 2 (x^2 - 1) y = 0 $$

To find $n$, substitute $y = x^n$ into the differential equation and see what has to be true in order for this to simplify to $0 = 0$.

To find the other solution, once you know what $n$ is, substitute $y = x^n g$ and you'll get a simpler equation for $g$ (the method is called Reduction of Order).

Comment: I did indeed mean that. I'll change the question

Comment: @Robert, how did you know the first form of the equation did not have a solution? Well spotted.

Comment: OK, that worked out simpler than I expected, thanks :)

Comment: @SimonS, substitute in $y = x^n$ to the original equation and you find $x^{n-2} ((n^2-3n+2) x^2 - n^2 + n - 2) = 0$.
You'd need both $n^2 - 3n+2 = 0$ and $-n^2 + n -2 = 0$, which can't happen.

Comment: If you changed the first $x^2-1$ to $x^2+a$, you'd get instead $n^2 - 3 n +2 = 0$ and $a n^2 - a n - 2 = 0$, which have a common root iff $a = 1$.